# multi_match with wildcards and boost

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to use `multi-match` with *wildcard* fields like so: `"fields" : [ "A*", "B*" ],`.
Now, I want the hits in any of the A fields to show up higher than those in the B fields.
So my assumption is that `"fields" : [ "A*^5", "B*^1" ],` should work. It does not, result order is the same irrespective of whether the 5 is on the A or B.

Oh, and this is Amazon ES (v1.5.xx). Eventually I want edgeNgram with term queries, but below example is shorter with stock phrase_prefix:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test123'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test123/type1/001 -d '{"A_01": "Solace"}'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test123/type1/002 -d '{"B_64": "Solitude"}'
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test123/_search?explain' -d '{
    "query" : {
    "multi_match": {
        "query" : "Sol",
        "fields" : [ "A*^5", "B*^1" ],
        "type" : "phrase_prefix"
    }
    }
}'
```

I must be overlooking something (simple), I'm afraid. Any pointer greatly appreciated!

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#_literal_fields_literal_and_per_field_boosting

Answer (score 0):

please, try in this way :

```
"query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query":{
            "bool":{
               "should":[
                  {
                     "multi_match":{
                        "query":"Sol",
                        "type":"cross_fields",
                        "fields":[
                           "A*^5","B*^20"
                        ]
                     } 
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @Luca, I shall dig into `cross-fields` again, in combination with `edgeNgram`! Above does not really work and shows no hits, since the prefix aspect is lost, and just "Sol" is not in the index.